# UIActivityViewController completion handler executes before the view controller disappears from the screen

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am using UIActivityViewController to present sharing options and I want to display another view controller when the UIActivityViewController is dismissed by the user or when the animation that follows "activityDidFinish:(bool)completed" gets over. When I try to present the other controller in the completion handler of the UIActivityViewController, I get the following warning and the second VC does not get displayed at all!

**Attempt to present <_UIViewController: 0x1e16f020> on <###> while a presentation is in progress!**

```
UIActivityViewController activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:selectedAssetsURL applicationActivities:nil];

[activityVC setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
    NSLog(@"completed");
    //Present another VC
}];
```

The question is, how to know when the UIActivityViewController disappears from the screen? Even the -ViewDidAppear method of the view controller which presents the UIActivityViewController does not get fired!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this link there's good information about how the UIActivityViewController works:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch26.html#_activity_view

Basically you can subclass the UIActivityViewController into another class and implement a method to know when it has been dissmissed.

```
UIActivityViewController* avc =
[[UIActivityViewController alloc]
    initWithActivityItems:@[myCoolString]
    applicationActivities:@[[MyCoolActivity new]]];
```

Here’s the preparatory part of the implementation of MyCoolActivity:

```
-(NSString *)activityType {
return @"com.neuburg.matt.coolActivity"; // make up your own unique string
}

-(NSString *)activityTitle {
    return @"Be Cool";
}

-(UIImage *)activityImage {
    return self.image; // prepared beforehand
}

-(BOOL)canPerformWithActivityItems:(NSArray *)activityItems {
    for (id obj in activityItems) {
        if ([obj isKindOfClass: [NSString class]])
            return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

-(void)prepareWithActivityItems:(NSArray *)activityItems {
    self.items = activityItems;
}
```

To perform the activity, we implement one of two methods:

```
-(void)performActivity {
// ... do something with self.items here ...
[self activityDidFinish:YES];
}

-(UIViewController *)activityViewController {
    MustacheViewController* mvc = [MustacheViewController new];
    mvc.activity = self;
    mvc.items = self.items;
    return mvc;
}
```

And then MustacheViewController would have code like this:

```
- (IBAction)doCancel:(id)sender {
    [self.activity activityDidFinish:NO];

}
- (IBAction)doDone:(id)sender {
    [self.activity activityDidFinish:YES];

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I subclassed UIActivityViewController and in the ViewDidDisappear method of the new activity VC, called a delegate method in the main VC.